# Application Engine Program - NULL Insert Error occuring

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine, peoplecode

I have the below Application Engine program that I am modifying slightly and I am now getting a NULL Insert error (Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EFFDT', table 'XXX.dbo.PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR'. Within the `While` block there is a `SQLExec` statement:

`SQLExec("SELECT A.VENDOR_ID FROM PS_ITM_VENDOR A, PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM B WHERE A.SETID = B.SETID AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID AND A.VENDOR_SETID = B.VENDOR_SETID AND A.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID AND A.VENDOR_ID = :1 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND A.ITM_ID_VNDR = :3 AND A.ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY = 1 AND B.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :4 AND B.CONVERSION_RATE = :5", &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &VendorId_check);`

The program needs to be modified to allow new records to be inserted where there is not already an existing UOM (UNIT_OF_MEASURE) so I removed references to UNIT_OF_MEASURE to be as follows so that the program evaluates to the Else conditional:

`SQLExec("SELECT A.VENDOR_ID FROM PS_ITM_VENDOR A, PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM B WHERE A.SETID = B.SETID AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID AND A.VENDOR_SETID = B.VENDOR_SETID AND A.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID AND A.VENDOR_ID = :1 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND A.ITM_ID_VNDR = :3 AND A.ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY = 1   AND B.CONVERSION_RATE = :4", &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &ConvRate, &VendorId_check);`

However when I remove the UNIT_OF_MEASURE SQL and Variable from the above code block then I get an NULL insert error on the EFFDT column of the table ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR. It seems as if the &UOM variable defined in the &SQL CreateSQL is not carrying forward into the Insert SQL code. Why is this happening and what can I do to correct and still be able to use the original instance/value of &UOM when inserting a new row?  Below is the entire program step:

```
Local SQL &SQL;
Local string &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &PriceVndr, &Oprid, &PriceStatus, &VendorId_check, &insert_cols, &insert_select, &insert_where, &insert_sql, &Error, &MaxEffdt, &ItmField;
Local date &Effdt;
Local Record &ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR, &REC, &MASTER_ITEM_TBL;

&Oprid = "'BATCH'";
&PriceStatus = "2";
&Error = "N";

MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "**** BEGINING OF VALIDATION ERRORS ****");

&SQL = CreateSQL("SELECT VENDOR_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, ITM_ID_VNDR, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, CONVERSION_RATE, PRICE_VNDR, %DateOut(EFFDT), ITEM_FIELD_C10_B FROM PS_GH_ITM_PR_UPDT ORDER BY VENDOR_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, ITM_ID_VNDR", &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &PriceVndr, &Effdt, &ItmField);

While &SQL.Fetch(&VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &PriceVndr, &Effdt, &ItmField)

   SQLExec("SELECT A.VENDOR_ID FROM PS_ITM_VENDOR A, PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM B WHERE A.SETID = B.SETID AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID AND A.VENDOR_SETID = B.VENDOR_SETID AND A.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID AND A.VENDOR_ID = :1 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND A.ITM_ID_VNDR = :3 AND A.ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY = 1   AND B.CONVERSION_RATE = :4", &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &ConvRate, &VendorId_check);

   If None(&VendorId_check) Then;
      &Error = "Y";
      MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, &VendorId | " " | &InvItemId | " " | &ItmIdVndr | " " | &UOM | " " | &ConvRate | " " | &PriceVndr | " " | &Effdt | " " | &ItmField | " " | &Error);
   Else;
      MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, &VendorId | " " | &InvItemId | " " | &ItmIdVndr | " " | &UOM | " " | &ConvRate | " " | &PriceVndr | " " | &Effdt | " " | &ItmField | " " | &Error);
      &CurrentDateTime = %Datetime;
      &Oprid = %OperatorId;
      &RECITEM = CreateRecord(Record.ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR);

      /*SQLExec("SELECT TO_CHAR(C.EFFDT,'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C WHERE C.INV_ITEM_ID = :1 AND C.VENDOR_ID = :2 AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :3 AND C.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(C1.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C1 WHERE C.SETID = C1.SETID AND C.INV_ITEM_ID = C1.INV_ITEM_ID AND C.VENDOR_SETID = C1.VENDOR_SETID AND C.VENDOR_ID = C1.VENDOR_ID AND C.VNDR_LOC = C1.VNDR_LOC AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = C1.UNIT_OF_MEASURE AND C.CURRENCY_CD = C1.CURRENCY_CD AND C.QTY_MIN = C1.QTY_MIN)  ", &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt);*/
      SQLExec("SELECT C.EFFDT FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C WHERE C.INV_ITEM_ID = :1 AND C.VENDOR_ID = :2 AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :3 AND C.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(C1.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C1 WHERE C.SETID = C1.SETID AND C.INV_ITEM_ID = C1.INV_ITEM_ID AND C.VENDOR_SETID = C1.VENDOR_SETID AND C.VENDOR_ID = C1.VENDOR_ID AND C.VNDR_LOC = C1.VNDR_LOC AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = C1.UNIT_OF_MEASURE AND C.CURRENCY_CD = C1.CURRENCY_CD AND C.QTY_MIN = C1.QTY_MIN)  ", &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt);

      SQLExec("%SelectAll(:1) WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND VENDOR_ID = :3 AND UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :4 AND (CONVERT(CHAR(10),EFFDT,121)) = :5", &RECITEM, &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt, &RECITEM);
      /*SQLExec("%SelectAll(:1) WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND VENDOR_ID = :3 AND UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :4 AND EFFDT = :5", &RECITEM, &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt, &RECITEM); */
      &new_UNIT_OF_MEASURE = &RECITEM.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.Value;
      &REC = CreateRecord(Record.ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR);
      &REC.SETID.Value = &RECITEM.SETID.Value;
      &REC.INV_ITEM_ID.Value = &RECITEM.INV_ITEM_ID.Value;
      &REC.VENDOR_SETID.Value = &RECITEM.VENDOR_SETID.Value;
      &REC.VENDOR_ID.Value = &RECITEM.VENDOR_ID.Value;
      &REC.VNDR_LOC.Value = &RECITEM.VNDR_LOC.Value;
      &REC.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.Value = &RECITEM.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.Value;
      &REC.CURRENCY_CD.Value = &RECITEM.CURRENCY_CD.Value;
      &REC.QTY_MIN.Value = &RECITEM.QTY_MIN.Value;
      &REC.EFFDT.Value = &Effdt;
      &REC.EFF_STATUS.Value = &RECITEM.EFF_STATUS.Value;
      &REC.PRICE_VNDR.Value = &PriceVndr;
      &REC.UNIT_PRC_TOL.Value = &RECITEM.UNIT_PRC_TOL.Value;
      &REC.EXT_PRC_TOL.Value = &RECITEM.EXT_PRC_TOL.Value;
      &REC.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL.Value;
      &REC.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL.Value;
      &REC.USE_STD_TOLERANCES.Value = &RECITEM.USE_STD_TOLERANCES.Value;
      &REC.QTY_RECV_TOL_PCT.Value = &RECITEM.QTY_RECV_TOL_PCT.Value;
      &REC.UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.BU_PRICE_STATUS.Value = "2";
      &REC.STD_PRICE_STATUS.Value = "2";
      &REC.LEAD_TIME.Value = &RECITEM.LEAD_TIME.Value;
      &REC.OPRID_MODIFIED_BY.Value = &Oprid;
      &REC.LAST_DTTM_UPDATE.Value = &CurrentDateTime;
      &REC.PRICE_CHANGE.Value = &RECITEM.PRICE_CHANGE.Value;
      &REC.Insert();

   End-If;

   /* DR - 10/11/2018 - Added field ITEM_FIELD_C10_B (&ItmField) to CSV file layout and insert into PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL (&MASTER_ITEM_TBL) */
   If None(&ItmField) Then;
      &Error = "Y";
      MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, &VendorId | " " | &InvItemId | " " | &ItmIdVndr | " " | &UOM | " " | &ConvRate | " " | &PriceVndr | " " | &Effdt | " " | &ItmField);
   Else;
      SQLExec("UPDATE PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL SET ITEM_FIELD_C10_B = :1 WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND SETID = 'SHARE' ", &ItmField, &InvItemId);
      /* Else;
       &REC1 = CreateRecord(Record.MASTER_ITEM_TBL);
       &REC1.ITEM_FIELD_C10_B.Value = &ItmField;
       &REC1.SETID.Value = "SHARE";
       &REC1.INV_ITEM_ID.Value = &InvItemId;
       &REC1.Update();
    End-If;  */

   End-If;

End-While;
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "**** END OF VALIDATION ERRORS ****");
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, " ");
```

Comment: The error message is that the EFFDT field is null.  Did you also modify the &SQL = CreateSQL("SELECT VENDOR_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, ITM_ID_VNDR, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, CONVERSION_RATE, PRICE_VNDR, %DateOut(EFFDT), ITEM_FIELD_C10_B FROM PS_GH_ITM_PR_UPDT... line?  This is where the &effdt variable is populated.  You need to figure out why this is blank.  I'm kinda guessing you removed unit of measure from there as well as the alignment of the variables isn't right now.  but just a blind guess

Comment: Figured it out - Was stupid not to go back and check the original csv file (File Layout input) as I discovered that the EFFDT was blank in the file. Thanks for the feedback!